# Install dependencies of PHP extensions

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've started learning Docker and now I'm building my own container with PHP7 and Apache. 
I have to enable some PHP extensions, but I would like to know how do you know what packages(dependencies) should be installed before installing the extension.

This is my Dockerfile at the moment:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

In this case, to enable `gd` extension, I googled the error returned on building step and I found that it requires the package `libpng-dev`, but it's annoying to do these steps for every single extension that I want to install.

How do you manage this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

The process is indeed annoying and very much something that could be done by a computer. Luckily someone wrote a script to do exactly that: [docker php extension installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer)

Your example can then be written as:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

#get the script
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

#install the script
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync

#run the script
RUN install-php-extensions gd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do, install php and some php extensions and tools. Things that I usual need...

```
# Add the "PHP 7" ppa
RUN add-apt-repository -y \
ppa:ondrej/php

#Install PHP-CLI 7, some PHP extentions and some useful Tools with apt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
php7.0-cli \
php7.0-common \
php7.0-curl \
php7.0-json \
php7.0-xml \
php7.0-mbstring \
php7.0-mcrypt \
php7.0-mysql \
php7.0-pgsql \
php7.0-sqlite \
php7.0-sqlite3 \
php7.0-zip \
php7.0-memcached \
php7.0-gd \
php7.0-fpm \
php7.0-xdebug \
php7.1-bcmath \
php7.1-intl \
php7.0-dev \
libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libedit-dev \
libssl-dev \
libxml2-dev \
xz-utils \
sqlite3 \
libsqlite3-dev \
git \
curl \
vim \
nano \
net-tools \
pkg-config \
iputils-ping

# remove load xdebug extension (only load on phpunit command)
RUN sed -i 's/^/;/g' /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own Dockerfiles involves trial and error - or building on and tweaking the work of others.

If you haven't already found this, take a look: https://hub.docker.com/r/chialab/php/

This image appears to have extensions added on top of the official base image. If you don't need all of the extensions in this image, you could look at the [source](https://github.com/Chialab/docker-php) of this image and tweak it to your liking.